# Passing attributes to Carrierwave uploader without ORM

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I am using Carrierwave in Rails 4 without mounting it to specific Model
and tried to pass my atrribute through initialize method so that store_dir can know where to store file.

```
class CustomFormUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  attr_reader :custom_form

  def initialize(custom_form)
    @custom_form = custom_form
  end

  def store_dir
   "uploads/custom_form/#{custom_form.id}/"
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fill => [64, 64]
  end
end
```

When I run that test:

```
let(:uploader) { CustomFormUploader.new(custom_form) }

before do
  CustomFormUploader.enable_processing = true
  uploader.store!(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, '/spec/fixtures/passport.jpg')))
end

context 'the thumb version' do
  it 'should scale down an image to be exactly 64 by 64 pixels' do
    uploader.thumb.should have_dimensions(64, 64)
  end
end
```

then gets an error coming from initialize

```
 ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
```

Any idea how to pass attribute to uploader without getting errors?

Comment: Why do you have to create a an `initialize` method just remove that and pass a too dummy options to it CustomFormUploader.new('Photo','path') and all will work

Comment: You are completely right. Dummy attributes look weird but it works great! Thanks

Comment: I want to correct my mistake even the dummy argument arent needed

Answer (score 2):

In the controller.rb

```
uploader = MyUploader.new(special_var)
uploader.store!(params[:icon])
```

In the my_uploader.rb

```
def initialize(special_var)
  @special_var = special_var
end

def filename
  "#{@special_var}.#{file.extension}"
end
```